# Delete NSObject from model

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have created a file in Swift called infoModel. This is used to pass info from one ViewController to another, and the info is written in a label. This works perfectly, but I want to be able to delete that info, or at least remove it from the label.

I have tried to set label = nil, but the info pops back in when I change to a different viewController and back.

How should I go about to remove the data?

Code infoModel:

```
import UIKit

class infoModel: NSObject {
    var info: String = ""
    var info2: String = ""
    var info3: String = ""
    var info4: String = ""

    func currentInfo() -> String {
        //return a string with the current info
        return info + "" + info2 + "" + info3 + "" + info4 + ""
    }    
}
```

And in view controller:

```
class collectViewController: UIViewController {
    var myInfo = infoModel()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        infoLabel.text = myInfo.currentInfo()
    }
}
```

It´s the infoLabel I want to remove from.

*Edit: The app is collecting info from users. The way that it does that, is simply that the user is pressing a/some button/buttons that represents the suitable values for that specific user. The information is then displayed in a different View Controller. If the user presses the wrong button, I want them to be able to delete/remove the information and start over. The removebutton is in the same View controller that the infoLabel is. 
When all the information is correct, the user then pushes another button that writes to Firebase Database.

So my goal is that the user is able to delete/remove the info, and start over.

Comment: I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the model to stay updated even if you destroy the controlller and create it again?

Comment: @MarcoPappalardo I updated my initial question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set initial value to `myInfo`, make it an optional:

```
 var myInfo: infoModel?
```

and

```
infoLabel.text = myInfo?.currentInfo()
```

Now if there is no model, nothing will be set.

Also, you can automatically update the label using:

```
var myInfo: infoModel? {
   didSet {
      _ = self.view // load the view if not loaded
      infoLabel.text = myInfo?.currentInfo()
   }
}
```

Now just setting `myInfo = nil` will clear the label.

Comment: Thank you for that! That did the trick with deleting the data from the label. But it also somehow block so that new information cannot be written after deleting. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Neccer There is no magic there - when you change the value of `infoModel`, the label gets updated. I would assume that after deleting (assigning `nil`) you are not assigning a new instance of `infoModel`?

Comment: I updated my initial question with a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the model as a container of your data and changes. 
when the user presses the various buttons, you need to update the model, and when the user clicks the remove button, you need to update the model to reflect that state.

Instead of setting the entire object to nil, set the inside variables to nil, so that the model object always exist. You will need to do more unwrapping.

```
var info: String? = nil
var info2: String? = nil
var info3: String? = nil
var info4: String? = nil
```

If you don't want to do that, you will need to check the nullability of your model and create a new one when it is nil (as Sultan explained in the other response)

(I could also suggest you use a struct and not a class)

You then need to redraw your UI when the model is updated.
I think in your simple case even running `setNeedsDisplay` on the view of the controller should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the issue with not being able to re add data to the label just by doing this:

```
 myInfo?.info = ""
 myInfo?.info2 = ""
 myInfo?.info3 = ""
 myInfo?.info4 = ""
```